# drawing rectangles in c#

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I need to draw a set of rectangles, something similar to a calendar which is made up by 28-31 rectangles, but based on their coordinates and width/height (from a database table). I need to be able to add/draw on each of those rectangles, such as adding a smaller square plus some text, on the top of the original rectangle.  My question is what should I use to accomplish that?

Comment: Where is your code and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I haven't started coding yet, just a question to find a good way to start it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void DoSomething()
{
    //these values are just example, should be from a source
    int x=15, y=20, width=100, height=80;
    string bgColor = "#fafafa";

    Panel pnOuter = new Panel();
    pnOuter.Attributes.Add("style", "position:absolute; text-align:center; left:" + x + "px; top:" + y + "px; width:" + width + "px; height:" + height + "px; background-color:" + bgColor + ";");
    Label lbHeader = new Label();
    lbHeader.Text = "Some Header";
    lbHeader.Attributes["class"] = "Header";
    pnOuter.Controls.Add(lbHeader);

    Panel pnInner = new Panel();
    pnInner.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:50px; height:40px; text-align:center;");
    Label lbText = new Label();
    lbText.Text = "some text";
    lbText.Attributes["class"] = "SomeStyle";
    pnInner.Controls.Add(lbText);

    //add inner panel to outer panel
    pnOuter.Controls.Add(pnInner);
}
```

Comment: Please do not simply throw code in the ring as answer. Explain what it does and why it helps answering the question.